# Нужна помощь с установкой MXE

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, кросс-компиляция

Я начинающий программист, и ранее кодил только из под Windows. В настоящий момент на РС стоит 10 версия. Появилась необходимость компиляции из под Ubuntu, в результате чего было решено использовать Ubuntu интегрированную в Windows 10. Согласно инструкциям на [официальном сайте MXE](http://mxe.cc) я скачал дистрибутив с GitHub и установил все зависимости, после чего запустил `make`. Однако я получил:

```
Failed to build package binutils for target i686-w64-mingw32.static!
------------------------------------------------------------
Makefile:849: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/git/mxe/tmp-binutils-i686-w64-
mingw32.static/binutils-2.28.build_'
Makefile:803: recipe for target 'build-only-binutils_i686-w64-
mingw32.static' failed
make[1]: *** [build-only-binutils_i686-w64-mingw32.static] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/git/mxe'
```

Поиск информации по форумам и интернету в целом не дал результатов. Я пробовал и очищать `$PATH` и переустанавливать зависимости прямо из репозитория, но безуспешно. Также пробовал пропускать неустанавливающиеся пакеты с помощью `EXCLUDE_PKGS`, но в таком случае компиляция не удается. Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Перестать заниматься ерундой, поставить убунту в виртуалку и собирать пакеты к ней.

Судя по тарджету `i686-w64-mingw32.static` , собрать оно пытается таки экзешник под форточку.

[Мануал](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/creating_packages), как вообще собирать пакеты под линукс прямыми руками, а не виндузятничать.